# Can you apply LIMIT on MySQL before LEFT JOIN another?

Tags: mysql

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 LIMIT 5 
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS table_1.id = table_2.id 
WHERE 1
```

Otherwise the engine takes all of table_1 before applying the join, then limiting which can slow the query down massively (with massive tables).

Comment: “[Should I use a subquery to `LIMIT` a table before `JOIN`ing?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/168874/124755)”

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do it by joining on a subquery instead of an actual table. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM table_1 LIMIT 5) as subq
    LEFT JOIN table_2 ON subq.id = table_2.id WHERE 1
```

Comment: there's a mistake on 3rd line, replace AS by ON