# does LIMIT have effect before or after JOIN?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, limit

It's a simple question - I just found different answers to this so I'm not sure. Let me describe:

If you have a query, like this one:

```sql
SELECT logins.timestamp, users.name
FROM logins 
LEFT JOIN users 
ON users.id = logins.user_id
LIMIT 10
```

This basically would list the last 10 entries of the `logins` table, replacing the `user_id` with the `username` over a JOIN.

Now my question is, does LIMIT take effect while the JOIN happens (so that it only joins the first 10 entries) or after the JOIN? (Where it would join the whole table, and then cut out the first 10 entries).

I'm asking this because the sample table `logins` will have many entries - and I'm not sure if a JOIN is too costly performance wise. If LIMIT would only case 10 JOIN's to happen, that wouldn't be a problem.

A second question that came up with this: Is the functionality the same, if a DISTINCT is added? Will it still stop, at 10 entries? And no, this isn't going to be ordered by ORDER BY.

Comment: *This basically would list the **last** 10 entries of the logins table* -- no, it wouldn't. No `ORDER BY` clause = no guaranteed ordering.

Comment: @Dcoder but the 'default' ordering is affected by the table inserts, right? So if you suppose that you're never going to `UPDATE` any row, but only do `INSERT`s, the order will always be the INSERT order, correct? - for this issue I'm only using the table as a history table, whitout manipulating the data at any later point

Comment: As far as I know, each vendor can implement default ordering as they see fit, so the results will usually be sorted according to whatever index was used in the query - this way the engine doesn't need to spend any extra time on ordering.

Comment: How to make LIMIT act before JOIN: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405432/can-you-apply-limit-on-mysql-before-left-join-another

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't worry. The LIMIT will happen at the same time with the join: MySQL will not read through the entire logins table, but fetch line by line (joining each time on users) until it has found 10 lines.

Do note that if a users.id appears two times in the table, the JOIN will duplicate the logins line and add each users line. The total amount of lines will still be 10, but you'll have 9 logins.

Comment: +1. From what I know, you're right, but it might be implementation-specific. For example, someone might have implemented an engine that might do the `LIMIT` while the `JOIN` is executing **IF** there is no `ORDER BY` clause. I don't know of anything like this, it's just an idea :) .

Comment: An engine can indeed specify its own behavior. For an order by, the limit is always done AFTER the order. You need a key on your join-where-order-select fields.

Comment: thank you for the answer - yes, that order by probably changes the result of this question was clear to me - but I'll not use that (already inserting the lines in the correct date-order). I've gained a second question tough now - what is with DISTINCT? (I'll edit my question - please answer if you can, but I'll accept this answer now anyway since it's exactly what I needed to know)

Comment: Distinct is the same: it will feed row by row, discarding duplicates, until it has 10 remaining rows. It will stop after it sent 10 rows.